# Angularjs code works in desktop chrome, but not in mobile chrome

Tags: angularjs, html, google-chrome, ionic-framework, camanjs

I have created a codepen of what I am trying to do in in IONIC.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNjmoK

**HTML:**

```
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/camanjs/4.0.0/caman.full.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js">
  </script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div id="photo">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div id="filterContainer">
    <ul id="filters">
      <li> <a href="#" id="normal" ng-click="applyFilter($event)">Normal</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#" id="vintage" ng-click="applyFilter($event)">Vintage</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#" id="lomo" ng-click="applyFilter($event)">Lomo</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#" id="clarity" ng-click="applyFilter($event)">Clarity</a> </li>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**JS:**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var image = new Image();
  image.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 460, 460);
  };
  image.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
  image.src = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/colorhouse.png";

  $scope.applyFilter = function(event) {

    // Clone the canvas
    var clone = canvas.cloneNode(true);
    // Clone the image stored in the canvas as well
    clone.getContext('2d').drawImage(canvas, 0, 0, 400, 400);

    var theParent = document.getElementById("photo");
    theParent.removeChild(document.getElementById('canvas'));
    theParent.appendChild(clone);

    var effect = String(event.target.id).trim();

    Caman(clone, function() {

      // If such an effect exists, use it:

      if (effect in this) {

        console.log("Effect GOOD");
        this[effect]();
        this.render();

      } else {
        console.log("Effect ERROR");
      }
    });

  };
});
```

Inside the codepen an image is brought in and I apply a filter. Inside the codepen this is working. I then try to apply this into ionic, but it will not work. When I click a filter it goes as far as the code 'if (effect in this)' in the caman function and prints 'Effect is GOOD" in the console, but on the phone the canvas becomes white and that is it.

UPDATE: I have just noticed on my android device if I run the codepen from my mobile browser (chrome) it does not work. If I run it inside chrome on my desktop it does work. So it looks like a browser issue? Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: I don't think this is an issue with angular; I would suspect it has something to do with how mobile browsers handle the `<canvas>` element.  you might get better traction for your question with tags related to the device you are testing on, and canvas.

Comment: I have the same issue but I am using just angular. The code uses ngFor over JSON array. It works fine with desktop chrome or firefox but not in Android Chrome or Firefox. Android version 5 on CoolPad mobile. I am not using CamanJS, so how to disable hidpi with plain angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer.

> If a HiDPI display is detected, CamanJS will automatically switch to
>   the HiDPI version if available unless you force disable it with the
>   data-caman-hidpi-disabled attribute.

So I had to set this to true and now it is working

Comment: If you are still into it: Do you also faced problems with the speed of filtering big pictures using camanjs with angular´? It needs 14 seconds to perform the vintage filter on a 2000 x 2000 picture.

Comment: @Mulgard I changed routes. As much as I hate to admit it, hybrid application do not have the horsepower to perform these type of operations yet so I switched to developing in native code. It actually saved me time in development as I did not have to spend days trying to make certain cordova and other javascript code work.

Comment: Yes i know that. i prefer android and im a really good android developer. but if the customer wants hybrid he gets hybrid :D

Comment: @Mulgard I looked into this issue for a few months. I really don't believe there is a way to efficiently apply filters to a webview. On mobile devices, the canvas redrawing takes too much resources. You could try a way with webgl, the problem I found with this it only works on some devices, some are blacklisted and very buggy. I would let the client know, many devices cannot handle applying filters in a hybrid app and maybe look at a native approach.

Comment: I thought about using a css preview like this http://designpieces.com/2014/09/instagram-filters-css3-effects/  and perform the camanjs filter in the background.

Comment: @Mulgard I guess it all relies on your requirements. For instance, my images needed to be uploaded to a server. This approach would not work for me because my user could have to wait sometimes for a minute plus for the image to apply the filter to the canvas. From a UX perspective this was not acceptable for my application. Best of luck with your app.